# Accept decimals

Tags: ios, swift, math

I´m trying to make an app that lets you input height and ratio and it will calculate the area and so on. But when i type in let´s ay 4,2 or 4.2 it crashes or says bad execution. I have tried different ways in declaring in but I´m probably doing it wrong. I tried Float and Double with no luck. I will be really grateful for any help.

```
let atext: Int? = Int(radien.text!)
let btext: Int? = Int(höjden.text!)
let ctext: Int? = Int(sidan.text!)

let myInt = (atext! * atext!)
let tre = 3

let myInt2 = Double(myInt) * Double(M_PI) * Double(btext!)

let result = Float(myInt2) / Float(tre)
volymenSvar.text = "\(result)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your are force unwrapping `aText` and it fails.

`aText` is defined as `Int(radien.text!)` which can fail two times (radien.text! may fail, and its casting as Int may fail also)

What should do if cast those text as Double to allow the use of decimal number. Furthermore you should use conditionnal binding like in the following example:

In your function put the following code:

```
guard let radien = radien.text, höjden = höjden.text, sidan = sidan.text else { return }

let atext: Double? = Double(radien)
let btext: Double? = Double(höjden)
let ctext: Double? = Double(sidan)

if let a = atext, b = btext, c = ctext {
    let myInt = (a * a)
    let tre = 3

    let myInt2 = Double(myInt) * Double(M_PI) * Double(b)

    let result = Float(myInt2) / Float(tre)
    print("\(result)")
}
```

The guard statement will prevent you from getting errors if there is no text in your textFields.

The conditionnal binding (`if let`) will prevent you from crashing if the conversion from text to Double failed

Comment: Hi thanks for your time but when i insert this code i Get this message "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(UITextField!)'" But only on let btext do you know hot solve that?

Comment: Corrected the answer, I had mispelled höjden as hödjen

Comment: But now i get the error message "Postfix '=' is reserved" at guard let

Comment: oops sorry it was just a equal sign to close to the name

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution:

```
    func asd()
    {
        let atext = getNumberFromString(radien.text)
        let btext = getNumberFromString(höjden.text)
        let ctext = getNumberFromString(sidan.text)

        let myInt = (Double(atext) * Double(atext))

        let tre = 3

        let myInt2 = Double(myInt) * Double(M_PI) * Double(btext)

        let result = Float(myInt2) / Float(tre)
        volymenSvar.text = "\(result)"
    }

    func getNumberFromString(string:String?) -> NSNumber
    {
        var result:NSNumber = 0
        if let aString = string
        {
            let formattedString = aString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: ".")
            let formatter = NSNumberFormatter.init()
            let number:NSNumber? = formatter.numberFromString(formattedString)
            if let aNumber = number
            {
                result = aNumber
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not like this?

```
var atext = radien.text.floatValue
var btext = höjden.text.floatValue
var ctext = sidan.text.floatValue

var myInt = (atext * atext)
let tre = 3

var myInt2 = myInt * Double(M_PI) * btext

var result = myInt2 / tre
volymenSvar.text = "\(result)"
```

Comment: HI @Boomerannge That dosen´t work for me, i get a error message that says "Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'String' operands" At the var myInt = (atext * atext)

Comment: @Kevin My bad, try var atext = radien.text.floatValue. I dont have my Mac so I cant try your code.

This answer by Mert should work:

let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
let number = numberFormatter.numberFromString(atext)
let numberFloatValue = number.floatValue